# Highcharts Using Data from Ruby on Rails Database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, graph, highcharts, chartkick

I currently have graphs on my Rails app that I implement using Chartkick. The following code is what I have in my view to render the actual graph. The path `graphs_site_hot_water_status_path(@site)` connects to a controller where I have all the logic for how my data is being queried from the database, which ideally would stay the same as it is quite complex.

```
 <%= line_chart graphs_site_hot_water_status_path(@site), colors: ['#AE42CE', '#DD6539','#093FF7', '#B2461F', '#A8BCFD', '#E68F6F'], refresh: @refresh_rate, ytitle: t(".fahrenheit"), xtitle: t(".timestamp") %>
```

My goal is to be able to format my graph using Highcharts customization, but I can't figure out how to input my data the same way when using Highcharts because I can't pass it into Javascript using Ruby code. Is there a way to pull my data in the same manner I currently am, but without using Chartkick?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use daru-view to use Highcharts with Ruby on Rails. For more about that, you can read these articles:

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-charts-with-daru-view-and-highcharts/
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/i-am-ruby-developer-how-can-i-use-highcharts/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found those articles, but didn't find them particularly helpful in figuring out how to feed my current data into Highcharts.